# Error after importing and upgrading expo project (v30 to v31)

Tags: react-native, expo

I did the steps below to import and upgrade an existing expo project and I end up with a weird error message that doesn't really help telling me if I did an import/upgrade mistake or if it is something else.

Steps:

1) Git cloning a project to a local folder

2) Run `expo start` in the terminal -> tried to open that with my device and expo client and got an error message: please upgrade to at least expo SDK version 31

3) I followed the steps in the expo doc to upgrade to v31 (only change version numbers in the `package.json` file)

4) Deleted `node_modules` and ran `npm install`

5) Cleared out some babel error and some syntax error in a RN module

6) Ended up with the error above...
(The app launched and displayed the login screen correctly and the error occurs after logging in.)

which is hard to track down and Id really like to know if it was caused by wrong importing/upgrading or where the hell it comes from...
Does anyone have a clue?

BTW: Im not sure if this is relevant but there are a bunch of other RN packages included in the `package.json` file where I didn't change any version numbers.

Those are:

```
"react-native-navbar": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.8.0",
"react-native-view-more-text": "^2.0.1",
"react-navigation": "^2.0.1"
```

Maybe those have to be changed too?

Error:

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {opacity}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.in RCTText (at Text.js:145)
    in TouchableText (at Text.js:268)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in ImageBackground (at VenueMarkerCircle.js:26)
    in VenueMarkerCircle (at VenueMarker.js:79)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in VenueMarker (at VenueMap.js:200)
```

Comment: Please show me the error-causing code.

Comment: hi hong, that's about every component that seem to cause this error...